# How to properly display all the values in the embedding arrays using php

Tags: php

How to properly get all the values in the array **embeddings** arrays eg **10,13,14,18,170**.
This code only display value **10**. how do I get the remaining **13,14,18,170**

```
$output= '

{"id":"e92b4fb9-273d-407b-86d0-aa9310d770e4","accountIdentifier":"account",
"team":{"identifier":"283992e6-19b2-43f9-bdcc-03a3be702bfe"}, "results":{"my-input":{"status":"SUCCESSFUL",
"endTime":"2021-11-06T19:58:32.589+0000",
"results.json":{"embeddings":[10,13,14,18,170]},"vico":{"exc":0,"sec":0}}}}
';


$json = json_decode($output, true);

//echo $id = $json["id"];
echo $rs1 = $json["results"]["my-input"]["results.json"]["embeddings"][0];

/*
foreach($rs1 as $row){
echo $emb = $row;


}
*/
```

Comment: `[0]` is the first item, so you need to loop over `$json...["embeddings"]`

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved by looping through the embedings as per below

```
foreach($json["results"]["my-input"]["results.json"]["embeddings"] as $row){
echo $emb = $row;


}
```